# Categories are repeating for each subcategory

Tags: php, loops, categories

I am showing categories in Menu. Some categories have subcategories.

function for getting parent categories

```
function get_parent_category(){
        $query="select * from blog_categories where parent_id=0 
                ORDER BY 
                CASE id 
                    WHEN '2' THEN 1 
                    WHEN '1' THEN 2 
                    WHEN '3' THEN 3
                    ELSE id 
                END";
        $rows=array();
        $result=$this->query($query);
        while($row=$this->fetch_array($result)){
            $row['url']=$this->get_cat_url($row);
            $rows[]=$row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }
```

Function for subcategories

```
function get_child_category(){
        $query="select * from blog_categories where parent_id!=0";
        $rows=array();
        $result=$this->query($query);
        while($row=$this->fetch_array($result)){
            $row['url']=$this->get_cat_url($row);
            $rows[]=$row;
        }
        return $rows;
}
```

Showing on the page like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL ?>">Home</a></li>
    <?php 
         foreach($this->parent_category as $cat){
            foreach($this->child_category as $child_cat){
                if($cat['id']==$child_cat['parent_id']){
    ?>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo $cat['name'];?>
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><?php echo $child_cat['name']?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <?php
                }elseif($cat['parent_id']==0){
    ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $cat['url']?>"><span><?php echo $cat['name'];?></span></a></li>
    <?php
                }
     ?>

    <?php }}?>
```

**Output and Problem**

[image]

The Main category circle in red color is **seerah** which has two subcategories. showing **two times** for first one in drop down one subcategory and for second time second subcategory is showing.

**DB structure**

[image]

**What i wants:**

I wants to show each subcategories under each parent category without repetition , how can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you use var_dum for both $rows from **get_child_category()** and **get_parent_category()** to see sql result?

Comment: @shojaeddin yes, but how it solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i handled the problem

```
<?php 
         foreach($this->parent_category as $cat){
             $html = '';
             foreach($this->child_category as $child_cat){
                if($cat['id']==$child_cat['parent_id']){
                    $html .=  '<li><a href="'.$child_cat['url'].'">' . $child_cat['name'] . '</a></li>';
                    // here is all child categories are saved in var.
                }
             }

             if ($html == '') {
    ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $cat['url']?>"><span><?php echo $cat['name'];?></span></a></li>
    <?php
            } else {
    ?>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo $cat['name'];?>
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <?php echo $html; ?> // here is displayed under parent category
                </ul>
            </li>
    <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Really Thank you, is there any updated solution ?

Answer (score 0):

To me it seem you did not split your html and loops properly here:

```
        foreach($this->parent_category as $cat){
            foreach($this->child_category as $child_cat){
                if($cat['id']==$child_cat['parent_id']){
    ?>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo $cat['name'];?>
            <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><?php echo $child_cat['name']?></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Usually whenever you have a loop you should have some output before any nested loop started. In your case first level loop is about Categories which should become an `<li>` of parent main menu `<ul>`.

I think. You need to transform this fragment to:

```
    foreach($this->parent_category as $cat){ ?>
        <li ...>
          ...
          <ul ...> <?php
            foreach($this->child_category as $child_cat){ ?>
                <li>...</li> <?php
            } ?>
          </ul>
        </li> <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do not have repetitive value in $rows, why you use this part again for $cat['name']?

```
elseif($cat['parent_id']==0){
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $cat['url']?>"><span><?php echo $cat['name'];?></span></a></li>
<?php
            }
```

when in first part of foreach you create

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo $cat['name'];?>
```